# NAO robot running Gentoo based OS cannot connect to Wi-Fi automatically

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, gentoo, nao-robot

I am using NAO robot for my Masters Thesis. It is running OpenNAO OS Version 2.1.4.13. This OS is Gentoo based.

The problem I am facing is that it doesn't automatically connect to one specific Wi-Fi hotspot in my lab. I need to get this robot online on that specific network. The Wi-Fi is listed in Network Section on NAO's webpage. If I connect to the robot using a lan cable and then selects that specific wireless SSID listed on NAO's webpage, it'll connect fine. But it doesn't connect automatically after reboot. It used to connect to the same Wifi SSID without any hassle a few days ago.

Please tell me what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the connection forced in your app : the "connection manager" service will help (http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/connectionmanager/).